# Updating Flash textbox text via ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textarea

I created a text area on my stage using the text tool, then converted it to a MovieClip symbol. I called it `ScoreLabel` and I clicked "Export for ActionScript". I named the instance of the text area `scoreLabel`. However, when I do this in my code:

`scoreLabel.text = this.score;`

it doesn't change. That line is in my `Main.as` file, which is the document class. How can I change the text shown in this text area using ActionScript? Maybe I need to import a library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, don't export for ActionScript - it's not necessary in your case.

You also need to assign a `String` to the `.text` property, so you have do something like this if `score` is a `Number` type:

```
scoreLabel.text = score.toString();
```

Do you get any errors, and is `scoreLabel` within scope from your document class, or nested in another container?